# Dynamically Turn Off and On URL formatting

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

In AngularJS you can dynamically add class formatting to elements using the `ng-class` attribute. I want to dynamically change whether some text is displayed as plain text or link a hyperlink.

I am also using bootstrap but `<a>` isn't defined as a class like h1 - h5 are.

For example, for `<h1>` I can just do this in AngularJS:

```
<div ng-class="'h1'">This will be displayed as a heading 1.</div>
```

But this didn't work to display as a url:

```
<div ng-class="'a'">This will be displayed as text, but I want it to be a URL.</div>
```

So after the answer from Asiel Leal Celdeiro I just had to add the working code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>AngularJS Example</title>

    <!-- JQuery for Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <p ng-class="{'btn btn-link': isURL}">This can be plain text or formated like a URL.</p>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isURL">
        Make it look like a link
    </label><br>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.isURL= false;
    }]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of <div> could you use <a> tag for the link? It seems adding all styles to the div 'a' class would be more work than using the instrinsic <a> tag.

Comment: Did you try using the `ngSwitch` attribute? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Comment: Building a directive based on ng-switch isn't horrible. But, I just can't believe I am the first guy in history who wanted to dynamically switch off and on the URL style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED**
If you really need it to be a `div` you can use:

```
<!--myController: angular controller on this partial view-->
<!--isURL: indicate whether this text is a URL or not-->

<div ng-class="{'btn btn-link':myController.isURL}">{{myController.text}}</div>
```

or if you can put an `a` or a `button` you can use:

```
<a ng-class="{'btn btn-link':myController.isURL}">{{myController.text}}</a>
```

or

```
<button ng-class="{'btn btn-link':myController.isURL}">{{myController.text}}</button>
```

All of them will be displayed as a URL if the `myController.isURL` expression is true when it's evaluated in by angular and as plain text if not. It basically, puts the classes *btn* and *btn-link* if the expression is true.

Comment: OK, well you did give me a hint. I can dynamically add use the "btn btn-link" class and it basically looks like the <a>. I will code up a plunker and put it here.

Comment: Yeah! I just edited my answer. I though you would extrapolate what I wrote, but, anyway ... sorry, here it is :)

Comment: OK!! Now that's an answer! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Toddsden for the edit suggestion. You were right!

Comment: I thought it worked out so well, I just had to add a working copy above!